# Bootstrap3: what is standard Structure and Layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a lot of tutorial about bootstrap elements.

But I want to know where I must use nav/header/container/row/well/panel/section

for example..Do it needs use row for column 12?

1- currently I do it this way:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid"> /*only for top navbar*/
    <nav>  
</div>

<div class="container"> /* for body */
    <header></header>

    <main class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
   </main>

   <footer class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </footer>
</div>

</body>
```

Is it true?

2- Is this format true or necessary?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

3- which one is standard?

```
<div class ="well">
    <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-*"></div> </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class="well"> <div class="col-md-*"></div>  </div>
</div>
```

4- dose it need use "container" class for all section or only for parent section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1:- yes it's a correct method. whenever you want to use bootstrap column classes like **col-xs-12** in their first parent you must put class " row ".

for 2:- this is true. method also accessory.

for 3:- first option is correct.

for 4:- depends of need of page design. if all site are in same container with then you can put it in parent class.

Comment: #3 - "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."... http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

All options you mentioned are correct.

However, below written structure makes sense. That means if you are using `col` in `container` or `container-fluid` it should be in `row`.

```
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-*-*">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

If anytime you want to check how well your bootstrap is written, you can check it on http://www.bootlint.com/

Comment: your suggested link " http://www.bootlint.com/ " is very helpful to check our bootstrap code structure.  thanks mate :)

Comment: Bootlint is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

> But I want to know where I must use nav/header/section/footer

Well all these fields are only for semantic purpose, actually they all could be `div`. In the future or even now it is **best practise for SEO** to use `nav` for navigation, `footer` for the footer etc. For example `header` should be used to introduce content, it often contains `<h1> - <h6>` tags.

There are many informations to this in the web, here is a [reference](http://www.webconfs.com/html5-seo-article-27.php)

All the other bootstrap classes are just styles which you could apply by yourself. A `container` for example can be used once for all of your content if you never need a full width element, but sometimes you have a situation where you need a full width element (f.e. an image) then you dont want to wrap all of your content into container.

[Here you want to use multiple containers and not one for everything (Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18994/)

Hope this helps you a bit.